# Backbone collection find I want only one result

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, find

I'm working with find Backbone and I have 20-30 results, I need the first result and I don't have the id for filter for id.

```
model = coleccion.find(
    function(e){
        return (
           e.get('car').category === data_category &&
           e.get('full_empty') === 0 &&
           e.get('idprovider') === data_provider
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use collection.at(0) if you want to get the first model.
Or collection.shift() if you want to get the first model, then remove this model from the collection.
Read more at [Backbonejs Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection)

Answer (score 2):

You can use findWhere method:

```
collection.findWhere(attributes)
```

Comment: Probably OP won't be notified unless you comment below the question, since he didn't participate in comments for this answer.