# Backbone multiple atributtes with object inside objects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, find

I'm trying filter my collection with findWhere. The filters full_empty and idprovide are working ok but I don't know as filter for category of the car.
I need the filters together

**My collection:**

```
{
"full_empty": "0",
"idprovider": "AA",
"car": {
    "category": "LL"
}
```

**The code**

```
model = coleccion.findWhere({
    full_empty: 0,
    idprovider: data_provider,
    car: {category: data_category}
});
```

Comment: at least accept the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34288316/2333214) for your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34288257/2333214) that helped you to come up with this before asking new questions. Asking new questions based on previous answers without  accepting them or giving any feedback will only discourage people from answering your questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do this instead:

```
var coleccion = new Backbone.Collection();
var data_provider = 'AA';
var data_category = 'LL';
coleccion.add({"full_empty": "0","idprovider": "AA","car": {"category": "LL"}});
coleccion.add({"full_empty": "0","idprovider": "AB","car": {"category": "LY"}});
coleccion.add({"full_empty": "0","idprovider": "AC","car": {"category": "LY"}});
console.log(coleccion.findWhere(function(_model){
    var model = _model.attributes;
    if (model.full_empty == 0 && model.idprovider == data_provider && model.car.category == data_category){
        return _model;
    }
}));
```

output:

```
B…e.Model {cid: "c41", attributes: Object, collection: B…e.Collection, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
```

Pay attention to the `_model` vs `model` variable.

PS. I used `==` instead of `===` because in your example you're comparing `0` to `"0"` try and make that as uniform as possible since `==` sometimes turns around and bites you in the butt. -- You've been warned.

Comment: `==` will bite only if you don't know how it works. People who discourage it's use doesn't understand how it works. It's a language feature.

Comment: @TJ I know its a language feature, i just stay the HECK away from it always unless i absolutely need that "feature" (which at the top of my head i've used a total of 0 times); this does NOT sit well with me: `0 == '' // true`, `0 == '0' // true` -- this does: `0 === '' //false` and that is what i would expect and trust. Im not sure how familiar is OP with javascript, by the nature of the question i would guesstimate -- novice level, which i am in no  way putting down, i just wanted to bring attention to it.

Comment: `0 == '' //true` and that is what I would expect, because I know what are the falsy values in js and how `==` tries to convert its operands... I understand your concern about the OP, I suggest saying something along the lines of *"better use `===` until you learn how `==` actually works, because..."* Please don't inject the *totally unpredictable butt byting evil sort of* feeling ;) `==` works as per defined rules and it can reduce the lines of code in certain cases

Comment: Fair enough. OP, what he/she said ^ :P (sorry i don't know your gender)